# Why does jQuery change event not work with select option?

Tags: javascript, html, events, jquery

The following code should enable the second select element (id=ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.8.) when the value in the first select element (id=ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.9.) changes, but it doesn't work and I've exhausted all the options I can think of, including those suggested already on this site. **(NOTE: the element ids must be these values, hence I'm not using # to select them, as that doesn't work).**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("input[id='ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.9.']").bind('change',function() {
   alert ('this script runs');  
   $("input[id='ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.8.']").removeAttr('disabled');

 });
});
```

If I substitute the enabled select (id=ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.9.) with a button and the change event with a click event; it works. So why not with change event on the select element?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can select by `id` using the `#` character. Secondly you need to escape the `.` in the `id` attribute otherwise the selector engine will look for an element with the id `ANSWER` which also has `TTQ`, `MENSYS` and `9` as classes. Try this:

```
$("#ANSWER\\.TTQ\\.MENSYS\\.9\\.").bind('change', function () {
    alert('this script runs');
    $("#ANSWER\\.TTQ\\.MENSYS\\.8\\.").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cFKuG/)

Comment: THANK YOU! All working now. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, even though it's a small issue.

Comment: Won't single slash instead of double slashes do ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Nope: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.9.").bind('change',function() {
   alert ('this script runs');  
   $("#ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.8.").removeAttr('disabled');

 });
});
```

`select` is not `input`( i.e. text input)

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `.` in the `id`

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer, even though it's a small issue.